# Magento Nominal Items Matrix Rate

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using magento and I have matrix rates to handle the shipping, I've just setup a product with a recurring profile, magento's knowledge base says this for recurring profiles "The list of available shipping methods during the shopping cart checkout is restricted to the fixed only (Fixed, Table Rates, and Free)." however I want to know if any one has been successful in making matrix rates work with recurring profiles? Im currently looking into this but not getting very far
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/how-to-enable-more-shipping-methods-for-nominal-items-recurring-profile-prodcuts

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question and the full results are here

[Magento nominal items and matrix rates](http://www.webamondo.co.uk/blog/magento-matrix-rates-recurring-profiles-nominal-items/)